# How can I change canvas with click function?

Tags: jquery, function, canvas, click, 2d

This is my demo [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vEEPS/2/)

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="random"></canvas>
```

**jQuery**

```
function Random() {
    var length = 9,
        charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
        retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    return retVal;
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("random").getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "30px Codystar";
ctx.fillText(Random(), 30, 30);
$("#random").click(function () {
    ctx.fillText(Random(), 30, 30);
});
```

My Question 1-font does not work the first boot and 2-click function does not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to use the function [`clearRect(x,y, w, h);`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clearrect.asp) to clear the canvas before writing on it again.

Something like:

```
$("#random").click(function () {
    ctx.clearRect ( 0,0,1000,1000 );
    ctx.fillText(Random(), 30, 30);
});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vEEPS/3/

Comment: Thanks super but i can't understand why font does not work the first boot

Comment: That's another question. I would recommend you to add another question for it.

Answer (score 0):

I went through following [link](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-modify-shape-color-on-click/)

and found that it can help you to understand the click functionality on canvas.